Unpopular kid hooks up with a pretty and popular girl
I'm trying to find the name of a film about a (not too popular) kid in school who hooks up with a pretty and popular girl.
I think the film is 20-30 years old.
Some scenes I recall:
He gets her to agree to go out with him after footing the bill for cleaning her dress.
During the course of the film I think he slowly comes out of his shell, and gains some popularity while he is with her.
Towards the end of their agreement, things slip back to how they were.
At one point, they're sitting at benches (outside? cafeteria?). There is a confrontation during which someone slams a baseball bat onto the table and says something about a 'pitching arm'
I think I recall a scene where he is hitch-hiking and she is driving a convertible (though I might be wrong on this part)
I was very young and can only recall fragments. I have no idea who starred in it unfortunately. But these fragments haunt me. I need to find and watch this film in order to get it out of my head!

Sounds like Can't Buy Me Love from 1987 with Patrick Dempsey.

[Outcast] Ronald Miller has had a crush on the beautiful Cindy Mancini for years - who doesn't even know his name. Cindy's idea of a Saturday night includes parties while Ronald's is poker games. In addition, Cindy is dating the former football star turned college pro - who has been giving her the cold shoulder. Cindy finds herself in a desperate situation when she borrows her mother's $1000 suede dress, without permission, and ruins it. The only person who has the money to replace the dress, without her mother finding out, is Ronald. However, Ronald tells her that the only condition for him giving her the money is if she poses as his girlfriend for a month. 

Here's the trailer:




Yes! That's the one. Just watched a few scenes online; Might not be a particularly good film (will have to watch it), but now, almost 30 years on, I can put this to rest. Thank you Walt :)

"former football star turned college pro".  I know those aren't your words, but that doesn't even make sense!  :o)
